# CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h file not found

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I'm developing an app in which a graph is drawn using coreplot. When I run the project on the system in which it is developed there is no problem. When I move it to other system and then take a build it shows the following error

CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h file not found

How can i solve it?

I'm not able to create ipa of this project too. I'm now creating it from build products. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set header search paths and library search paths.
Please refer  [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120420110857/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application) to know how to do that..

Comment: Thanks Dimple that was really helpful. It worked thanks a lot.

Comment: but one more doubt Dimple why am i not able to create ipa directly. I'm using xcode 4.2

Comment: For that you need to build and archieve

Comment: no dimple i know that but the problem is that after we archive we dont get the ipa file. Instead it generates only a build products option. I'm currently taking ipa from it. It is possible to create it from the build products without any problem. But still i would like to know why this is so.

Comment: sorry again i know that too i didnt meant about it. I'm sorry if i'm confusing you. Let me clarify i would like to create an ipa file in xcode4.2 by simply doing build and archieve. But it is not allowing to do so instead of creating an ipa file it creates an archieve file. ie what i meant.

Comment: Link is down, but there are more answers to this question on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Use this import instead if you're using CorePlot 2:

```
#import <CorePlot/ios/CorePlot.h>
```

Other solution that I found to work is to add

```
use_frameworks!
```

to your Podfile. This way you can use import like this:

```
#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>
```

Comment: Thanks Baki excellent solution. I am working with CorePlot 1.6 and I put use_frameworks! in my pod file and solved problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an other solution is to add the header search path /core-plot-master/framework, then when others error appear select recursive in front of the added search path, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xcode 10 and I was getting this error, what worked for me is that setting "User Header search path" with the same values as the "Header search path", I am using an old version of CorePlot and they imported the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h using quotest hence I believe XCode is looking @ User Header search path to search the header files.

Answer (score 0):

For core-plot version 2.4 I did this to get it to compile:

1. In "targets->Build settings->Header Search Paths" I added core-plot/CocoaPods
2. I replaced:

   #import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"

with:

```
#import "CorePlot.h"
```